# Msal with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Curious if anyone has used MSALjs with RequireJS. I seem to be stuck getting the exports to register correctly. I can see the msal.js file is loaded in both the Visual Studio IDE and the Chrome Sources. The project using RequireJS 2.3.6 and MSAL 1.1.3.

**require.config.js**

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
    .....
        "msal": "https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.1.3/js/msal"
    }
};
```

***main.js***

```
require([
    .....
    , 'msal'
], function (
    .....
    , msal
) {
    var _Msal = new Msal; //Msal is not defined
    ....
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a couple days now.

This is how it should read. *Thank you jasonnutter!*

**require.config.js**

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
    .....
        "Msal": "https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.1.3/js/msal"
    }
};
```

***main.js***

```
require([
    .....
    , 'Msal'
], function (
    .....
    , Msal
) {
    var msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "obfuscated_clientid",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
            redirectURI: "http://localhost:58541/"
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };

    const MsalAgent = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig); 
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `"Msal"`, instead of `"msal"`?

Comment: Try both? There is a known issue that dynamic imports have to use `"Msal"`, I think this is also what's causing the behavior you are seeing. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1118

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the confusion on that. Unfortunately, we can't fix this until the next major version, but we'll make sure it gets fixed then.